# Doom blue screen of death (BSOD)

Tags: technical-issues, doom-2016

Recently I have bought Doom and I tried the Multiplayer. Sometimes I have issues with connection, but that's not the case.

After playing one or two rounds, then the game crashes to Desktop and after this, a Blue Screen of Death appears to the screen, which says something about IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

I have to say that I've played the Beta without any problems.

My PC has Windows 10, with a Nvidia GTX 770 and the CPU is an AMD FX8350, so the game should run fine.

Comment: Is your pc overclocked?

Comment: Nope, I haven't changed anything

Comment: Apparently, [**IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms854226.aspx) means your drivers (in case of games, it's usually the graphics drivers) are buggy. Are they up-to-date?

Comment: OK, it seems that my graphic card drivers are not updated. I am going to install the latest drivers and inform about the results.

Comment: Obviously the problem is that you're trying to run it in windows. Exit to Dos first, and make sure you've loaded XMS, not EMS ;)

Comment: Nice one Mazura jejeje. Well, I have updated the graphic drivers. Yesterday looked fine, today I have played some single player without problems. But, when I quit the game, after 5 minutes or so, the PC crashed with a BSOD telling something about Pagination. This only happened when I played Doom. After restarting the PC (without playing DooM), no Blue Screens. I don't know if it would be something related to RAM (however, I have 16 GB, far more than enough), or the game itself. Perhaps Bethesda has to work with this issues, I don't know. I'll keep trying and see if this happen again.

Comment: When I google "Pagination" I get a bunch of stuff about Wordpress. My first thought was your page file is screwy. (Do you have WP or a PF?) Is this running through Steam? Disable overlay; run in off-line mode. Are your service packs up to date? Any problems in device manager? Perhaps one of the "re-distributional" packs that came with Doom doesn't like your OS install. Also, golly gee, you're running into problems in W10? Say it ain't so ;) (there's always a reason why Windows comes with a "free downgrade" - this is it)

Comment: "after 5 minutes or so, the PC crashed with a BSOD telling something about Pagination." This is key information, please edit it in (especially since it happens when the game is not running - this is quickly becoming a SU question...). And try to catch the full error codes next time.

Comment: Well, I had suffered several bluescreens (IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, PAGINATION and other which I don't remember), and it was only when I played Doom, so it was the game. Since I installed the latest Nvidia drivers, no more bluescreens appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I updated the Nvidia drivers (the version 368.22, which I installed yesterday) no more bluescreens where shown, so I think that the problem is solved.